# Automatically set a value inside a field in a database form, from a value in another table

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, `Products` and `Orders`. `Products` has primary key of `productID` and `Orders` has foreign key of `productID`. Products has the cost of each product under `Final Price`. The `Orders` form has a `Unit Price` field which I would like to automatically fill in from the `Products` table.

I understand this can be done with `DLookup`, so maybe I am just using the expression incorrectly. I believe that `DLookUp` must consist of:

- Field to look up from
- The table in which this field is located
- The expression; in this case the parenting of foreign and primary keys between `productID`.

My attempt:

```
DLookUp([Final Price],[Products],[productID=Products!productID]
```

Look up `Final Price` from the `Products Table`. Compare `productID` in the form to `productID` in `Products` table.

Upon typing in a value to trigger this expression, the return result is unexpected `£0.00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your criteria should be in quotes rather than brackets.

```
=DLookUp("[Final Price]","Products","[productID]=" & [productID])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. The amount returned is from the first record - but then stays like that. Maybe I am putting this expression into the wrong place?

Comment: Tried it - the outcome is different, but still not as expected. This time, the result returned stays at a fixed `£0.00`.

Comment: Got it to work - it was just me being an idiot. Thanks for the help.